# Как запретить создание кластеризованной метки при определённых условиях?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты, yandex-maps-jsapi

Что нужно:
для первой и последней placemark выводить свои иконки.

Варианты:

1. Координаты первой и последней placemark различаются. В этом случае проблем нет, выводятся нужные иконки.
2. Координаты первой и последней placemark совпадают. В этом случае отдельные иконки первой и последней заменяются на одну общую, прописанную для кластерных меток.

Вопрос:
Возможно ли запретить создание совмещённых (кластерных) меток, если входящие в неё метки - первая и последняя метка кластера?
Апи яндекс карт - 2.1.47.

Comment: Зачем вы добавляете метки ("первую" и "последнюю") в кластеризатор, если вы не хотите, чтобы они группировались в кластера?

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, в Вашем случае поможет стандартное свойство кластеризатора (и ObjectManegerа) maxZoom. Если его задать, объекты на зуме больше максимального никогда не кластеризуются.